# How can I identify the exact model of my AMD GPU?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I'm struggling to find out the precise model of my AMD GPU. `lspci -v | grep VGA -A 1` returns:

```
VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics] (rev 45) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
DeviceName: Onboard IGD
```

The [AMD drivers download website](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download)  offers me five different models, but I don't know which to choose. I managed to find some specs in the store I bought the GPU from - but all I find is "AMD Radeon R5".

Comment: Maybe these might help:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_accelerated_processing_unit_microprocessors#Beema.2C_Notebook_APU

Comment: Helpful link ! Studying it now. Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

Execute this command instead : `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`  The output looks like this :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)  
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501  
Kernel driver in use: i915
--  
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)  
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501  
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

In this example you can see that the model of the GPU NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 860M is shown.

Comment: The command you provided is powerful.  Command returned:
`VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics] (rev 45)
 DeviceName: Onboard IGD
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics]`  however nothing that would say "Radeon R5 x-series" or "Radeon R5 230" etc.

Comment: @MarkAlexa Please see the information at the bottom of -> https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2346980 : "That IS the complete marketing name/model. To date, the R4 series only has one GPU in it, so there are no additional model numbers in the name like parts in the R7 family (for example)." The user who asked there has the same GPU model (Hewlett-Packard Company Mullins AMD/ATI Radeon R4/R5 Graphics).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to go to the asus website, the same link you mentioned, and click the 'all list', and then go down to the name which includes your laptop's processor along with the GPU. Like for me it was:

AMD A8 7410 Radeon R5